# Using InctantUI to create dynamic user interfaces in Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I have been struggling with creating Dynamic user interfaces or forms in Codenameone. InstantUI will work with PropertyBusinessObjects. However, the current documentation assumes that these will be defined a priori. I want a situation where I can go from a map to InstantUI. My real use case is to create an InstantUI from a JSONObject. IS this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no support for that in the `InstantUI` class as the `PropertyBusinessObject` contains far more information than just key/value pairs e.g. it contains type information, labels, constraints etc.

So no that's not possible. However, you can look at the [source of InstantUI](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/properties/InstantUI.java) and use that as a starting point to create your own implementation that doesn't require these things or fetches them from a different source.

Comment: I will do that. But I wonder if I can create a PropertyBusinessObject on the fly.

Comment: We didn't design it with that purpose in mind so I doubt it, it's possible this can be done but I have no idea how and I'm not sure the use case is there.